# Trying to understand this SQL injection from VulnHub

Tags: sql-injection

I am trying to understand The Pentester Lab challenge [here](https://www.vulnhub.com/entry/pentester-lab-web-for-pentester,71/) at VulnHub.

After I translated [this](https://www.hackplayers.com/2017/02/pentesterlab-web-for-pentester-1-sqli.html) tutorial into English, at **Exercise 2** I was presented with the following SQLi which completes the challenge:

```
http://pentesterlab/sqli/example2.php?name=root'/**/union/**/select/**/1,(select/**/name/**/from/**/users/**/limit/**/3,1),(select/**/passwd/**/from/**/users/**/limit/**/3,1),4,5/**/and/**/'1'='2
```

The `/**/` is used to bypass the WAF which filters space characters.

The `union select 1` part just displays the number 1 circled in red.

The brackets `( ... )` are used syntactically to prevent the DBMS from misunderstanding the *limit* part, as `limit 3,1,select` and as `limit 3,1,4,5`, which would both be incorrect without the brackets.

The `limit 3,1` part means after the third result, output the next one, so it gets one name and one password, circled in blue.

Provided my understanding above is correct, I cannot understand why the tutorial author included the `4,5` part, nor why they included the `'1'='2` part which evaluates to false?

Comment: Wouldn't of help to ask the author in comment section ?

Comment: I did, but the author has to accept them which will take time as the tutorial is a few years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why they included the '1'='2 part which evaluates to false

```
$sql .= $_GET["name"]."'";
```

In the code snippet above, notice that a `'` is appended to the end of the `$_GET["Name"]` (which is all being appended to the `select` command).  In the exploit you're providing the closing `'` after the name (root) so you need to account for the appended `'`.  You do this by adding the `and '1'='2` to the end so when the `'` is appended it is proper syntax.  In pseudo code it's equivalent to "In the fifth column I want to put the value of "true (5) and false (1=2)" which is false (0).  When I tested the exploit it didn't matter whether the `and` evaluated to true or false.  I'm guessing it's to prevent anything unexpected from happening with a true value.

> why the tutorial author included the 4,5 part

**TL;DR** - The `union` operator in SQL requires the same number of columns from all `select` statements.  The `users` table has five columns so the union select needs five columns.

**The Details**

As you can see from this screenshot, the `users` table in the lab has five columns.

[image]

And the query in the `php` script is selecting all the columns:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users where name='";
$sql .= $_GET["name"]."'";
```

The exploit is using a SQL `union` operator to return additional information.
The `select` after the union must have five columns because the `users` table has five columns.  When you perform a `union` in SQL:

- Every SELECT statement within UNION must have the same number of columns.
- The columns must also have similar data types
- The columns in every SELECT statement must also be in the same order

Reading into it a bit further, the select in the `php` is populating the first row.  The select after the union is populating the second row. It's filling the value '1' in the first column, the username in the second, the password in the third, and the values '4' and '5' in the fourth and fifth column respectively.

**References**
[MySql Union](https://www.w3schools.com/mysql/mysql_union.asp)

Comment: In the first paragraph, I am confused as to why doing AND False (because 1 is not equal to 2) would not cause the whole statement to fail. In programming languages like C, when using AND both sides must evaluate to TRUE. It is weird how it can be either true or false. I do understand it is to resolve the trailing ' symbol, another approach that works is to use two -- (%23%23). That was a very good answer!

Comment: @questioner it doesn't fail because it's only affecting the fifth column entry and the value it puts there.  In MySQL (maybe others), any non-zero number is a boolean true.  `5 and '1'='2'` is the same thing as entering `true and false` which returns false e.g. 0 for the value of the 5th column.

Comment: That made perfect sense. If I could actually see the 5th column in that SQL injection then it would contain the number 0, or 1 if I made the statement evaluate to true. You have been such a huge help, I have marked as accepted.

Comment: Would you have any idea about this other question? https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/262605/why-are-mysql-injections-more-limited-than-ms-sql-attacks